# Bad Signed JSON signature! parseSignedRequest PHP SDK 3.1.1 Facebook

Tags: facebook

I was having a problem with continuous redirect for my application that is basically requesting basic user info such as name, gender and location.
I went through too much headache until I decided to open up base_facebook.php and trace the flow. I ended up with commenting out the if block that checks whether **$sig** matches **$expected_sig** inside the parseSignedRequest function. The application worked fine and displayed the basic information about me. However I wonder if it is safe to do so?!!! and why $expected_sig does not match $sig any help would be appreciated thanks indeed

```
 protected function parseSignedRequest($signed_request) {
     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

     // decode the data
     $sig = self::base64UrlDecode($encoded_sig);
     $data = json_decode(self::base64UrlDecode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
      self::errorLog('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
      return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload,
                          $this->getAppSecret(), $raw = true);

    var_dump($expected_sig);
    echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
    var_dump($sig);
    // if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    //   self::errorLog('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    //   return null;
    // }

    return $data;
 }
```

Comment: please upgrade you PHP SDK version. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: You can try this [link](http://www.violato.net/blog/php/71-uncaught-curlexception-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cert-is-ok-when-implementing-facebook-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essential for security reasons. It verifies that the request is coming from facebook because only fb and you know the app secret.

Realistically the only variables that are going to screw this up is the facebook app secret or some sort of modification to the signed_request. I had this same issue when I was testing because I copied the signed request coming in wrong. Make sure to double check everything.

Answer (score 2):

I experience similar issue and just found that this is my mistake in supplying the correct configuration parameter when calling

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

Comment: This question was asked 8 (!) months ago. 2 months ago Facebook updated the SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk). 


The user who asked the question was last online on Aug 23... 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/1219081/user1219081